# can p4-git clone be configured to treat all files within a directory as large files

Tags: git-p4

I have a large repository with many binaries and other file types in perforce. With the largefileextensions configuration I can track certain file types for the GitLFS large file system. There is one directory with files in it that should all be treated as large files. Is there a way to configure p4-git clone so that any files within a directory are treated as large files without configuring all of the extensions of the files within the directory?